# how to shift text or anchor tag on right?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a list using CSS. I am able to make the list using `ul` and `li` elements. I am facing one issue: my text or `anchor` tag text shows below the `image`.

It should only be on the right side of the image. How can I achieve that?

```css
li a {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  //float:right
}
```

```html
<ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="content">
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63085179,w-40,h-40/63085179.jpg">
      <stname>Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets
        against Vikram Kothari
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63085077,w-40,h-40/63085077.jpg">
      <stname>BSF foils infiltration bid in Samba, ceasefire reported along LoC in Nowshera Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in
        arms procurement
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63084642,w-40,h-40/63084642.jpg">
      <stname>Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

[View on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/ruyodalulu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(changed answer after comment)

Use `display: inline-block` for images and texts. In this case you have to define a width for both so they both fit into one line. In my example the width for the text is `calc(100% - 46px);`, which is the full width of the container minus the width of the image.

Here's the result:

```css
li a {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul.content>li img,
stname {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
stname {
  width: calc(100% - 46px);
}
```

```html
<ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="content">
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63085179,w-40,h-40/63085179.jpg">
      <stname>Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets
        against Vikram Kothari
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63085077,w-40,h-40/63085077.jpg">
      <stname>BSF foils infiltration bid in Samba, ceasefire reported along LoC in Nowshera Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in
        arms procurement
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a xmlns="" href=""><img src="https://opt.toiimg.com/recuperator/img/toi/m-63084642,w-40,h-40/63084642.jpg">
      <stname>Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement Rotomac case: I-T dept files 6 charge sheets against Vikram Kothari Defence ministry admits to floundering ‘Make in India’, crippling delays in arms procurement
      </stname>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: still the text coming down or below image...it is wrong answer

Comment: i don't want text to come below image

Comment: then you have to use `display: inline-block` for images and texts, but in this case you have to define a `width` for both so they both fit into one line.

Comment: could you pls give jsbin link

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add something like the following styles

```
li img {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 20%;
}

li stname {
  width: 80%;
}
```

You need float the image left but you also need to set a width for the image and text so that the text never wraps under the image.

I have updated your jsbin: https://jsbin.com/layozexila/1/edit?html,css,output